# How can i improve this code to find rectangles and not only squares

Tags: c#, matrix

I have this code and I work finding squares of "0" in 2d arrays.

How can I make find rectangles and not only squares?

I'm having some difficulty doing this.

```
        // Set first column of S[,]
        for (i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            S[i, 0] = M[i, 0];
        }

        // Set first row of S[][]
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            S[0, j] = M[0, j];
        }

        // Construct other entries of S[,]
        for (i = 1; i < R; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < C; j++)
            {
                if (M[i, j] == 0)
                    S[i, j] = Math.Min(S[i, j - 1], Math.Min(S[i - 1, j], S[i - 1, j - 1])) + 1;                                      
            }
        }

        // Find the maximum entry, and indexes of maximum entry in S[,]
        max_of_s = S[0, 0];
        max_i = 0;
        max_j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                if (max_of_s < S[i, j])
                {
                    max_of_s = S[i, j];
                    max_i = i;
                    max_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Maximum size sub-matrix is: ");
        for (i = max_i; i > max_i - max_of_s; i--)
        {
            for (j = max_j; j > max_j - max_of_s; j--)
            {
                M[i, j] = 2;

                Console.Write(M[i, j] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Find any size rectangles and not only squares.

Comment: There is not much to be uderstood from your code, variable names are all mangled and you don't have any description on which is which.

Comment: I can´t even see any rectangle nor square, just meaningless arrays.

Comment: Sry, but SO dont let me put all the code, keep saying that is too much code. But here you can find the complete code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/

Comment: We don´t want your entire code, just the smallest possible that is able to reproduce your issue and understand what you want to achieve. See here for how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: be quite good to have some examples to illuminate the problem...e,g. here is an array which does "have rectangles", and here is one that doesnt

Comment: Also, this question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/